# Accessing np.array elements depending on another np.array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy.ndarray (arr)`, which contains multiple 3x4 arrays. In the other hand I have a 1xN `referenceArray`, which shows, which subarray should I take out from the `arr`.

```
arr=  [[1 2 3]
       [4 5 6]
       [7 8 9]
       [10 11 12]]

       [[13 14 15]
       [16 17 18]
       [19 20 21]
       [22 23 24]]

       [[25 26 27]
       [28 29 30]
       [31 32 33]
       [34 35 36]]
       .
       .
       .

referenceArray = [0 1 4 8 9]
```

E.g.

`arr[0]`gives me the subarray from `arr`

```
arr:[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
[10 11 12]]
```

and `arr[1]`

```
arr:[[13 14 15]
[16 17 18]
[19 20 21]
[22 23 24]]
```

My problem is, the elements and also the size of the `referenceArray` is changes dynamically. So, how can I access only those subarrays from `arr`, which depends on the written elements in `referenceArray` and append those in a new array?

Comment: How about `arr[referenceArray]`?

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution